# PHPStorm 2018.5.3 - deployment does not auto upload a file changed by a file watcher until the window is refocused

Tags: deployment, phpstorm

OK, so an odd problem here.

So I have a filewatcher setup to copy a file from it's source directory to another directory in the repo. I have deployment and automatic upload configured. So I change the file, the file watcher then copies it over. However, PHPStorm storm fails to immediately copy over the new file. It order to do this, I have to click over to another window (in this example, FileZilla but it could be any random window) then I click back over to PHPStorm and it instantly deploys the file. My only other choice would be to right-click and deploy to server.

Is there a simple way around this? It's extremely annoyed as it adds a second step before I can check how the updates to that file are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem sorted - you need to add the destination directory to the "Output paths to refresh" field. You will also need to close and reopen PHPStorm for the settings to work.